# php preg replace character inside container

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Is there a regular expression for `preg_replace()` that will replace a character in string if it is between a single/double quotes and round/square/curly brackets.

E.g.

```
$var = "(replace, here) not,here 'but, here' , [and, this too] , \"oh, escaped as well\", ";
echo preg_replace($pattern, ".", $var);
```

Would return:

```
(replace. here) not,here 'but. here' , [and. this too] , "oh. escaped as well",
```

I suck at regex. So any help will be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So long as matching parenthesis isn't important it can be done.

```
$var = "(replace, here) not,here 'but, here' , [and, this too] , \"oh, escaped as well\", ";
preg_replace( '/[(["'][^)\]"\'].*(REPLACEME).*[)\]"\']/', 'REPLACEWITH', $var );
```

This searches for any instance of `REPLACEME` after a `(`, `[`, `"`, or `'` and followed by a `)`, `]`, `"`, or `'` with no closing characters (`)`, `]`, `"`, `'`) in between.

The set of matched parenthesis is not a regular language, however, and therefore can not be expressed with regular expressions. So a string like `((replace, )here,)` becomes ambiguous and the second comma will not be replaced.

**Edit:** I realized I forgot to escape my single quotes. Fix'd (a few years late, but better than never)